# issue while creating VM using deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting below error code while creating VM and other resources using deployment manager.

error code :

```
Waiting for create [operation-1599546356618-5aec7686355d6-35c95719-d85f1e9d]...failed. ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1599546356618-5aec7686355d6-35c95719-d85f1e9d]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR   location: /deployments/quickstart-deployment/resources/quickstart-deployment   message: '{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"412","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":412,"message":"Precondition
    check failed.","status":"FAILED_PRECONDITION","statusMessage":"Precondition Failed","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxxxxxx/zones/us-central1-a/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

My Yaml file is :

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance   name: quickstart-deployment   properties:
    zone: asia-east1-b
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxx/zones/asia-east1-b/machineTypes/f1-micro
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxx/global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

Can somebody please check and help me to resolve this error.

Comment: **1.** Please update your question: at your `.yaml` you use `asia-east1-b` zone, but there's `us-central1-a` in the error message. **2.** Please have a look at the documentation [Creating a basic template](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template#creating_a_basic_template) and try to change provided example for your use case. **3.** Please check if you're able to create VM instance manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your `.yaml` accordingly to the documentation [Creating a Basic Template](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template#creating_a_basic_template):

```
$ cat vm.yaml 
resources:
- name: quickstart-deployment   
  type: compute.v1.instance   
  properties:
    zone: asia-east1-b
    machineType: zones/asia-east1-b/machineTypes/f1-micro
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

and it works for me:

```
$ gcloud deployment-manager deployments create vm --config=vm.yaml
The fingerprint of the deployment is b'J_pRfbjbVQy-MLN2gL9NGQ=='
Waiting for create [operation-1599649846919-5aedf80e40181-c0582c09-ed1da9db]...done.                                                                                       
Create operation operation-1599649846919-5aedf80e40181-c0582c09-ed1da9db completed successfully.
NAME                   TYPE                 STATE      ERRORS  INTENT
quickstart-deployment  compute.v1.instance  COMPLETED  []

$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME                   ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP      STATUS
quickstart-deployment  asia-east1-b  f1-micro                   10.140.0.2   XXX.199.YYY.111  RUNNING
```

**To solve your issue** follow the steps below:

1. Try to create VM instance manually.
2. Change your `.yaml` accordingly to the documentation [Creating a Basic Template](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template#creating_a_basic_template) or try my `.yaml`.

Keep in mind, that your `.yaml` should be formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create deployment using basic template which is provided by google, but one thing which i noticed that my VM is not acquiring any public IP by its own.(Public Ip column is blanked). Even same thing I noticed when I deploying VM manually.

Is there any recent changes which is done by google?

Comment: I've checked both deployments (example from the documentation and deployment I shared above) and both of them has no such issues.